# How to express the performance of loop & inner loop in big o notation?

Tags: scala, big-o

For below loop and inner loop to express the performance in big o notation is :

O(N squared) as its performance is proportional to the square of the size of the input data set.

```
var counter = 0
var counterval = 0;
for ((key, value) <- m2.par){
        for ((key2, value2) <- m2.par){
          counter = counter + 1;
           println(counter)
           }
        println(counterval)
      }
```

Is this correct ?

Comment: This question is more suited for cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It certainly is in no way Scala-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you consider the size of `m2` to be the input size and that increasing `counter` and printing it are both `O(1)` (which is a very reasonable assumption).